# trigger pipeline fails in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

trying to trigger a pipeline in another project.

```
trigger job:
    stage: triggers
    needs: [test_01]
    trigger:
        include: 
            - project: voodoo212/ourlordandsavior
              file: .gitlab-ci.yml
        # strategy: depend
```

the remote pipeline runs fine when run separately but fails when triggered from another pipeline.
anything I am missing here? the triggered pipeline do start running but seem like it is the same error I got when not passing cache path

```
$ ./configure.sh
/bin/bash: line 114: ./configure.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can trigger it through API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

```
script:
- curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I had the syntax wrong !
no need to use include to run it just

```
trigger job:
    stage: deploy
    needs: [test_01]
    trigger:
        project: voodoo212/ourlordandsavior
        strategy: depend
```